# I need help in constructing and proving an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Let V = $\begin{Bmatrix} a&a+b\\ 0&c \end{Bmatrix}$ where a, b and c are in F, and construct an isomorphism from V to $F^3$.

I let T(V) = $(a,b,c)$ or $(a,d,c)$, where $d=a+b$. I know this spans all of $\Bbb{R}^3$, is linear, 1-1 and onto. I proved linearity, but I really don't understand 1-1 / onto proofs and my textbook doesn't provide much help.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. If you don't mind, could you type out the whole question/problem? Is V a transformation matrix? What exactly is the isomorphism you are trying to prove/find?

Comment: What is V? Is it a matrix, is it a set of vectors? What is F, is it an arbitrary field? What thing spans all $R^3$? T is a linear transformation from where to where? How do you know it is injective and surjective? What does your textbook suggests as a proof?  Please try to to be clear in order for us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your space $V$ is
$$
V=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} a & a+b \\ 0 & c\end{bmatrix}
\biggm| a,b,c\in F\right\}
$$
which is a subspace of the vector space of $2\times2$ matrices over $F$, you can easily find a basis, because
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & a+b \\ 0 & c\end{bmatrix}
=
a\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+
b\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
c\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Send the first matrix in the basis to $(1,0,0)$, the second to $(0,1,0)$ and the third to $(0,0,1)$. So
$$
f\colon\begin{bmatrix} a & a+b \\ 0 & c\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto (a,b,c)
$$
and this is an isomorphism by construction.